# How do I start an animation after a previous one ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an animation function which plays all animations simultaneously.  This is not something that's desired, I want to play each animation after the previous one ends.  How would I do this?

```
canvas = document.getElementById("test");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function animateLines(name, x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke, width, duration){
    var count = 0;
    var ms = 10;
    duration = duration * ms;
    var counter;

    function countNumbers(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);

        count += 1;
        if(x2 > x1){
            ctx.lineTo((x1 + count), y2);
        }

        else if(y2 > y1){
            ctx.lineTo(x1, (y1 + count));
        }

        if((x1 < x2) && (count == x2)){
            clearInterval(counter);
        }

        else if((y1 < y2) && (count == y2)){
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        ctx.lineWidth = width;
        ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    $("#pause").on("click", function(){
        clearInterval(counter);
    })

    $("#play").on("click", function(){
        counter = setInterval(countNumbers, duration);
    })
}

animateLines("Line", 0, 100, 100, 100, "white", 5, 3);
animateLines("Line2", 150, 250, 350, 250, "red", 5, 2);
animateLines("Line3", 100, 0, 100, 300, "blue", 5, 1);
```

So basically, I want to hit play and have `Line`'s animation start.  When it finishes, have `Line2` start and when it finishes, have `Line3` start.

Comment: Use native [jQuery animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)--those have callbacks on completion which make them easily chainable.

Comment: jquery animations don't animate on the canvas though, do they?  Aren't they explicit to the DOM?

Comment: Along with what @dave suggested, you can also try using `.done` in jquery

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that you were animating a `canvas`. In that case I would probably use [$.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) or [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

This code must work for you. Sorry, I didn`t keep your code style and wrote all under one object, but I hope you understand whats happen there.

```
canvas = document.getElementById("test");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var anim={
    currentStep:0,
    steps:[
        {name:"Line", x1:0, y1:100, x2:100, y2:100, stroke:"yellow", width:5, duration:3},
        {name:"Line2", x1:150, y1:250, x2:350, y2:250, stroke:"red", width:5, duration:2},
        {name:"Line3", x1:100, y1:0, x2:100, y2:300, stroke:"blue", width:5, duration:1}
        ],
    count:0,
    ms:10,
    counter:0,
    draw: function(){
        var cur=anim.steps[anim.currentStep];
        ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(cur.x1, cur.y1);
        anim.count += 1;
        if(cur.x2 > cur.x1){ctx.lineTo((cur.x1 + anim.count), cur.y2);}
        else if(cur.y2 > cur.y1){ctx.lineTo(cur.x1, (cur.y1 + anim.count));}
        if((cur.x1 < cur.x2) && (anim.count == cur.x2)){anim.changeStep();}
        else if((cur.y1 < cur.y2) && (anim.count == cur.y2)){anim.changeStep();}
        ctx.lineWidth = cur.width;
        ctx.strokeStyle = cur.stroke;
        ctx.stroke();
        },
    changeStep: function(){
        anim.currentStep++;
        anim.count=0;
        if(anim.currentStep==anim.steps.length){clearInterval(anim.counter); console.log('stopped');}
        }
    };
$("#pause").on("click", function(){clearInterval(anim.counter);});
$("#play").on("click", function(){anim.counter=setInterval(anim.draw, anim.steps[anim.currentStep].duration*anim.ms);});
```

Comment: So basically, it just increments the draw function for the number of steps there are?

Comment: Yes, it increase currentStep after each step is reach end and function draw() just draw step which is set in currentStep. You can add as much steps as you need. One thing - duration will work only for first step. If You want that duration work for each step, you need to clear interval and set it again after increase of currentStep in changeStep() function.